# what does '-' stand for in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

What exactly are the uses of '-' in bash? I know they can be used for

1. `cd -`  # to take you to the old 'present working directory'
2. `some stream generating command | vim -`  # somehow vim gets the text.

My question is what exactly is - in bash? In what other contexts can I use it?

Regards
Arun

Comment: @Jonas: Bash **Scripting** is the name.

Answer (score 17):

That depends on the application.

```
cd -
```

returns to the last directory you were in.

Often `-` stands for `stdin` or `stdout`. For example:

```
xmllint -
```

does not check an XML file but checks the XML on `stdin`. Sample:

```
xmllint - <<EOF
<root/>
EOF
```

The same is true for `cat`:

```
cat -
```

reads from `stdin`. A last sample where `-` stands for `stdout`:

```
wget -O- http://google.com
```

will receive google.com by HTTP and send it on `stdout`.

By the way: That has nothing to do with your shell (e.g. `bash`). It's only semantics of the called application.

Answer (score 3):

`-` in bash has no meaning as a standalone argument (I would not go as far as to say it it does not have a meaning in shell at all - it's for example used in expansion, e.g. `ls [0-9]*` lists all files starting with a digit).

As far as being a standalone parameter value, bash will do absolutely nothing special with it and pass to a command as-is.

What the command does with it is up to each individual program - can be pretty much anything.

There's a commonly used convention that `-` argument indicates to a program that the input needs to be read from STDIN instead of a file. Again, this is merely how many programs are coded and technically has nothing to do with bash.

Answer (score 1):

From [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html):

> This can be done for instance using a hyphen (-) to indicate that a program should read from a pipe

This explains how your vim example gets its data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal rule here.

According to the context it changes

1. It is pretty much useful when you have something to do repeatedly in two directories. Refer #4 here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/6-awesome-linux-cd-command-hacks-productivity-tip3-for-geeks/
2. In many places it means STDIN.